# FileNotFoundException although using an absolute Uri in android

Tags: java, android, file, filenotfoundexception

I´m trying to email an image using javamail. But I get a FileNotFoundException:

```
05-22 15:05:29.300: W/System.err(29154): javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
05-22 15:05:29.300: W/System.err(29154):   nested exception is:
05-22 15:05:29.300: W/System.err(29154):    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/media/external/images/media/35367: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I think this is the part of the method which causes the exception:

```
        System.out.println(params[1]);
        File filename=new File(params[1]); // params[1]=content://media/external/images/media/35367
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);//uses aditional
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
```

But if I understood the API right an absolute uri isn´t a problem for a File-object.
And I think it isn´t possible that the file doesn´t exist, because right before this method I´m setting an ImageView by this uri. Could this be the problem? Something like that android automatically locks this file?

I also set Read and Write rights at the AndroidManifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Just comment if you need further information.

EDIT: 
I looked up the path to the image I´m trying to send and it differs completely from the path where it is saved...

Comment: Have you tried using javamail to send a message without sending an attachment? it's possible it's not related to the file you're trying to attach, but something else.

Comment: @StealthRabbi Sending a message without an attachment worked fine...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing this very issue - attaching images from dropbox (/storage) works fine but others, including native apps, fail - even with external file permissions on.

Comment: @RelicScoth yes! `/**Returns the real path from a relative URI*/
 private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
  
  String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
      
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
    
    int column_index = 
      cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index); 
 }` worked for me but it´s deprecated since api level 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I´m trying to email an image using javamail. But I get a FileNotFoundException

That is because what you have is not a file. It is an entry in a `ContentProvider`.

Get an `InputStream` on the content using `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver`. Then, use that with a `ByteArrayDataSource` instead of a `FileDataSource`. In theory, that should work, and at least should get you closer to something that works.

Comment: So how do I get a ContentResolver because getContentResolver() can´t be called caused by using it in an AsyncTask

Comment: @burnaut: Implement a constructor on your `AsyncTask` that takes in a `ContentResolver` and holds onto it in a data member. Then, use that `ContentResolver`.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
/content:/media/external/images/media/35367
```

is not valid path on your device. If you want absolute path you should have

```
/media/external/images/media/35367
```

Comment: I also tried this one, getting it by using uri.getPath().toString() but I keep getting the same exception and i used uri.isAbsolute() to verify that the uri I´m using is absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you left the extension of the image out of the uri?

For instance,
`/content:/media/external/images/media/35367.jpg` for a JPG image?

Comment: If I´m using System.out.println(uri.getPath().toString) the .jpg is missing but adding it to the String didn´t solve the issue

Comment: You have checked the image is a "jpg"?